# Robocopy - Copy files located in directory with a last modified date on only a single date in the past

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to create a batch file that copies files from one directory to another that have a last modified date on a selected date.

I have tried this command:

```
robocopy %from% %to% /MAXAGE:%current_date% /MINAGE:%current_date% /R:0 /E
```

where current date is the same on both minage and maxage. When I run this command I get 0 files copied. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have verified that I have files on the selected date within the folder structure. So the files are there. That is no the issue.

Comment: %current_date% is the last modified date of the files that I want to copy in yyyymmdd format.

Answer (score 1):

passing the same age in both `/minage` and `/maxage` does not trigger the copy of any file. You need to add one day to the `minage` parameter.

So, to copy all files of june 3rd 2016 you need to specify

```
/maxage:20160603 /minage:20160604
```

/MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.

/MINAGE:n : MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.

(If n < 1900 then n = no of days, else n = YYYYMMDD date). It says in the documentation for robocopy that a date in yyyymmdd will be accepted. Also it says that minage and maxage exclude dates older or newer than the supplied date so if I am applying the same date on both I assumed that it would exclude all other dates? Is this not correct?

Comment: /MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
 /MINAGE:n : MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
 (If n < 1900 then n = no of days, else n = YYYYMMDD date). It says in the documentation for robocopy that a date in yyyymmdd will be accepted. Also it says that minage and maxage exclude dates older or newer than the supplied date so if I am applying the same date on both I assumed that it would exclude all other dates? Is this not correct?